# JSON Schema validating a range of numbers for a integer property

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm using [TV4](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4) to validate my schema, and I saw that this lib use Json Schema model to validate a JSON.

But I didn't found a way to do a specific validation.

I have a integer property and this property can only have one of some numbers. For example, the valid number for me is, 10, 20, 30 and 40, so if I put some number different than these numbers, I need to show a validation error.

Has some way to do this specific validation in JSON Schema ?

Comment: It would be good if you could update your question to show what you have tried so far, as in what your code currently looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want an `enum` or you want your integer values to be multiples of 10.

For [`enum`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.5.1), you have an array of the allowed values. For example:

```
{
  "type": "string",
  "enum": ["red", "amber", "green"]
}
```

[source](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html#enumerated-values)

If you want values to be only multiples of a number, you want [`multipleOf`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.1).

```
{
    "type"       : "number",
    "multipleOf" : 10
}
```

[source](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html#multiples)

These links are for the draft-4 version of JSON Schema, as that's what the library you're using supports, however these key words are also present in the lates version of JSON Schema (draft-7 at the time of writing). You may consider using a differnet library which supports newer versions.

Comment: @Relenquestual not multiples of ten, but let me explain better the allowed numbers. I'm developing a bank integration, and the allowed type of payment has the following ID's: 10,15,20,22,30,40,50,60,80,90 and 98, so, the allowed numbers has to be these.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos OK, then you want the `enum` solution. It works for numbers as well as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify this JSON schema expression:

```
{
    "type"       : "number",
    "multipleOf" : 10,
    "maximum"    : 40,
    "minimum"    : 10
}
```